# Displaying image from Azure storage in android app

Tags: android, image, azure

I use Azure service for backend of my android app. I can load images to the storage and get the URIs from them, but when I tried to set image from uri in imageView, it is not showing. I use this:

```
imageView.setImageURI(itemUri)
```

I tried to create file from this uri and then set it in imageView, but it isn`t work too.

Comment: What happens when you try to access the image via URL in a regular browser?

Comment: How are you getting "itemUri"  ?  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please edit your question to show an example `itemUri`.

Comment: I have not any error, just imageView is epty. I solved it by using Picasso library.